# How to Check the Angular Reactive Form Validation When a Button is pressed

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I want to check the form validation when a button is pressed or to say it in another word I want web page to look like this exactly on button press.
[image]

Reactive form code I have written is given below.

```
    schemeForm = this.fb.group({
            bankDetails: this.fb.group({
                Name: [null, Validators.required],
                Branch: [null, Validators.required],
                acHolder: [null, Validators.required],
                acNumber: [null, Validators.required],
                IFSCCode: [null, Validators.required],
                passBook: [null, Validators.required]
            }),
    });


    get getbankDetails() {
        return this.schemeForm.get('bankDetails');
    }

    bankFormValid() {
        if (this.getbankDetails?.invalid) {
            this.getbankDetails?.markAsTouched({onlySelf: true})
            this.getbankDetails?.dirty
            console.log('invalid')
//here this code work properly But the colour doesn't change automatically to red.

        }
    }
```

Template Code:
https://gist.github.com/srbalakkl/d921c4c653704855e3540ed9fb8bbe4f

Comment: Angular add yours input with [formControl] the css indicate in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes). you can create, e.g. a .css `.ng-invalid.ng-touched{border:1px solid red}`

Comment: when i try to change formControlName to [formControl] it gives : error TS2339: Property 'Branch' does not exist on type 'ClaimSubmissionFormComponent'

Comment: sorry, my bad :(. When I said `[formControl]` I wanted to say an input with `formControlName` or `[formControl]`